# Finding the dimension of a polynomial that is a subspace of $V$

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, vector-spaces

Let $V$ be the set of all real polynomials $p$ of degree at most $2$, satisfying $p (0) = p(1)$. I have determined that $V$ is a subspace, but now must determine the dimension of $V$.

Say $p(x) = a + bx + cx^2$

I have plugged in numbers to get: $a + b+ c = a$
Standard basis of P2 is $[1,x,x^2]$

Now, I'm not sure how to find the basis and thus dimension, considering that it must satisfy $P(0) = P(1)$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the linear map $V\to \mathbb{R}^2$ given by $a+bx+cx^2\mapsto (a,b)$. It is injective because $c=-b$. Therefore it is an isomorphism and $dim V=2$.

If you want an explicit basis just pull a basis from $\mathbb{R}^2$. For instance, pulling $(1,0),(0,1)$ gives you $1,x-x^2$ as a basis for $V$.

Comment: That was quick! Does isomorphism just mean that b and c are equal and opposite?  I see that c=-b, but not sure how you go that the dimension was then 2? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Oh, ok. Well, an isomorphism $T:V\to W$ of vector spaces  is just a linear map with an inverse that is also a linear map. You can check that isomorphisms preserve dimension. Then $V$ has dimension 2 because $\mathbb{R}^2$ has dimension 2.

Comment: If you are not familiar with this, then just check that $1,x-x^2$ is indeed a basis for $V$.

Comment: Great, thanks. Isomorphism isn't actually part of our course, so I would have to show that 1, x-x^2 is a basis of V. I know how to show that but I'm not sure how you found x-x^2 (i see that you have used the fact b=-c) but how did you get to that answer as one of your vectors?

Comment: I gave you a bijection between V and $\mathbb{R}^2$ that is linear. Then I looked at a basis of $\mathbb{R}^2$, and looked at which elements of $V$ had this basis as image. Turned out $1$ goes to $(1,0)$ and $x-x^2$ goes to $(0,1)$

Answer (score 0):

For $p\in V$ let $p(x)=A(x-1/2)^2+B(x-1/2)+C$ with constants $A,B,C.$ Since $p(0)=p(1),$ we have $B=0$. So $p(x)=A(x-1/2)^2+C.$  Clearly $f=(x-1/2)^2$ and $g=1$ are linearly independent, and $p=Af+Cg.$

Comment: Thanks! How did you know to use the formula A(x−1/2)^2+B(x−1/2)+C? If you use a different one ie : A(x−1/4)^2+B(x−1/4)+C and apply the same constraints p(0)=p(1), you get that both a and b must = 0

Comment: For a polynomial $p$ of degree $2$ or less , if $p(c)=p(d)$ with $c<d$ either $p$ is constant or the graph of $y=p(x)$ is a parabola whose vertical axis is the line $y=(c+d)/2$ so the graph is described by $y=A[x-(c+d)/2)]^2 +C.$ .......If you take $p(x)=A'(x-1/4)^2 +B'(x-1/4)+C',$ with $p(0)=p(1),$ you will not get $A'=B'=0 ,$ but you will find constants $d,e,f$ such that $d A'+e B'+f C' =0,$ with $d  e f\ne 0,$ so $ B'$ depends on $A' $ and $C'.$  However it may not be obvious to you that this implies a dimension of $2$.